# How to make upside down exclamation in utf8

Tags: html, css

the site is utf-8, i'm using and upside down exclamation point as a warning.  instead of using an html code for an updside down exclamation, I'm using css 'content' and rotating it with bourban sass which outputs to vendor specific rotations.  the issue is:  it's not cross browser compatable.  the fallback is a right-side up exclamation, which i'm ok with...  but i'm wondering.  is there a better method?

```
.day:before{
    content:"!";
    @include transform(rotate(180deg));
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2%;
}

.day:after{
    content:"!";
    padding-left:2%;



}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the actual upside down exclamation mark. Alt+0161 as Mahan suggested?

Comment: You could always just use an i in the right font ;)

Comment: Especially for a warning, why would you rely on CSS, and on CSS features not supported by all browsers at that? Moreover, using an upside-down exclamation mark is correct for some languages, like Spanish, and simply incorrect for most languages.

Comment: That you to all that responded.  Great suggestions here.  Our client decided that they didn't like the upside down exclamation point.  So I'll have to use the solutions here for a future pet project.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you don't want to just write:

```
content: '¡';
```

There's the character escape sequence:

```
content: '\a1';
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the character you are looking for:

```
¡
INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK
Unicode: U+00A1, UTF-8: C2 A1
```

To insert it into a document, press `Alt+Ctrl+Shift+!` on Windows, or `Option+!` on the Mac.

Or, to print it in HTML without using Unicode, use either `&iexcl;` or `&#161;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.day:before{
    content:"\a1 ";
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2%;
}

.day:after{
    content:"!";
    padding-left:2%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="day">Fooo</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just press alt and type 173 and release alt and this will give you the real inverted exclamation mark.using complicated code will slow your  computer.